# If $F$ and $R$ are subspaces of vector space $E$, then $F \cap R \neq \varnothing$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to prove the following:

let $F \cap R$ intersection of vector subspaces $F$ and $R$ of vector space $E$, then $F \cap R \neq \emptyset$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A subspace of a vector space always has $0$.

Comment: @Jared, but $0 \in E $?

Comment: It's a vector space...

Comment: Garnak: Recall that ***every*** vector space, by definition, contains the zero vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: What vector must every vector space (or subspace, which is in its own right a vector space) contain?

Comment: null vector... is correct?

Comment: therefore "every vector subspace contains zero vector of space vector"... is correct?

Comment: The zero vector, if that's what you mean. $\varnothing$ means the intersection is **empty**, which it is not. The zero vector is a vector. Yes, you are right (second comment). So we know that at a minimum, ${\bf 0} \in F \cap R \neq \varnothing$

Comment: @amWhy.. okok thanks.. in effect if $0 \in F $ and $0 \in R$ then, by definition, $O \in F \cap R$... But, if $A$ is subspace vector then $A \neq \emptyset $ and $\forall a,b \in K, v,t \in E ( a\cdot v + b\cdot t \in A )$, then $(-1)\cdot v + (1) \cdot v = (-v)+v=0 \in A $... is correct?

Comment: Correct. Indeed, The intersection of two subspaces is again a subspace. It may have only the zero vector in common, but it may have more vectors in common as well, depending on F and R.

Comment: @amWhy....... thank you soo much!!!

Comment: You're welcome, Garnak!

Comment: @amWhy: Excellent exchange! =1